# Нужно к определенной ячейке по клику добавлять системное время и через минуту ячейка было заблокирована

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь так

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Time", "TimeOut2"
End Sub

Private Sub Time()
    Range("A3").Value = Now()
End Sub

Private Sub TimeOut2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Пытаетесь запустить обработку при открытии книги. Нужно - при выделении ячейки? Какой, на каком листе?  Для чего нужна задержка? В течение минуты разрешается производить какие-либо действия на листе? Добавлять только время или время и дату?

Comment: Функция `TimeOut2` смотрится очень коряво. 1. объекты по `ByVal` не передаются, только по `ByRef` и это поведение по-умолчанию. 2. Зачем передается аргумент `Target`, если нигде не используется? 3. не пишите действия с диапазонами через `Select`, если только не собираетесь демонстративно что-то выделить. Гораздо проще и правильнее в данной функции весь код привести к одной строке `Target.Locked = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записать в модуль листа

```
Option Explicit

Dim bFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = Now
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        If fTemporaryDelay() = True Then
            Target.Locked = True
            bFlag = False: Beep
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function fTemporaryDelay() As Boolean
    Dim t As Double, dTime As Double

    t = Now: dTime = 1 / 1440

    Do: DoEvents
        If Now - t >= dTime Then
            fTemporaryDelay = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

При выделении ячейки *A3* в нее записываются текущие дата-время и вызывается *UDF* `fTemporaryDelay`, которая задерживает время блокировки ячейки на указанный период. После выдержки ячейка становится защищаемой и звучит сигнал.

Если действия производятся на защищенном листе, защиту нужно снять/поставить:

```
    Unprotect ("pass1")
    Target.Locked = True
    Protect ("pass1")
```

где *pass1* - пароль защиты листа.

Время задержки задается переменной `dTime`. Например:

*1/1440*= 1 минута (1440 часть суток), *10/86400* - 10 секунд...

Если во время временной задержки нужно запретить работу на листе - закомментировать (или удалить) обработку прерываний ( `DoEvents`)

---

Дополнение.

Если лист защищать нежелательно, то `Locked = True` ничем не поможет. Да, ячейка будет с защитой, но защита действует, если защищен лист.

Можно защитить по-другому: если ячейка уже заполнена, то выделение автоматически смещается на другую ячейку. Процедура примет такой вид:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            Target.Value = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True

            If fTemporaryDelay() = True Then
                bFlag = False: Beep
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Если я перехожу с другой ячейку на А3, то значения также меняются, а мне бы хотелось после клика сделать ее только для чтения спустя минуты чтобы не было возможности редактировать

Comment: Т.е. сразу сделать только для чтения и через минуту защищенной? Объясните разицу между "*только для чтения*" и "*не было возможности редактировать*"

Comment: На VBA я пишу впервые и я точно не знаю есть ли такая фича в этом языке, но на примере языка C#, где есть свойство ReadOnly=True; На поле есть данные и она не изменяема.

Comment: Даже если *ReadOnly=True*, то какой смысл в выдержке времени?! Сразу защитить - не вариант?

Comment: Должна быть возможность изменения в течение одной минуты, после истечения минуты поле блокируется

Comment: Ваш первый комментарий к этому ответу читается как "казнить нельзя помиловать" - в зависмости от того, где поставить запятую, читать можно по-разному :) Надеюсь, теперь правильно понял. Добавлена переменная уровня модуля, отключающая реагирование на изменение ячейки.

Comment: Хотела бы поблагодарить Вас за оказанную помощь)Макрос блокирует всю страницу, нет возможности блокировать только ячейку в которой есть дата, которую мы создали при клике на ячейку?

Comment: Дополнил ответ еще одним вариантом